# how to find the range of group of matrices ???

Tags: matrices

like how can I find the range of the groupe (A^(k)) while k belongs to Z 
[This is matrix A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV02N.png)
like I wanna find the dimension  of the vector space E, which E=vect (A^(k))

[A ^(n)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6G26.png)

[A^(-n)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JGuH.png)

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ [solves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) $p_A(A)=0$ where $p_A$ is the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial), you have that $E=\mathrm{span}\{A^k:k\in\mathbb N\}$ is finite dimensional and you just need to find the smallest power of $A$ which is linearly dependent with all the previous powers.

You might find something interesting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: sorry But I didnt get it .. what is P() ..??

Comment: it's the characteristic polynomial, as i wrote

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton tells you that $E$ is finite dimensional and you have to check powers only up to $n$, where $n$ is the dimension of the vector space

Comment: well how can I find  the dimension of that vector space .. and what do U mean by checking the powers ?

Comment: You find the lowest $n$ for which $\{I, A, A^2, \dots, A^n\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia entry for minimal polynomial that I linked? All is clearly explained there

Comment: will you go angry if I say I'm not getting what you say ? :|
please please explain more if its O.K ..

Comment: Ok, here is an example. Let's say that you have a matrix $A$ for which the characteristic polynomial is $p(x)=x^3-2x^2+3x+1$. This means that $p(A)=A^3-2A^2+3A+I=0$. What do you get? That $A^3$ depends linearly on the previous powers, meaning $A^3\in\mathrm{span}\{I,A,A^2\}$. Right? But then you see that also $A^4,A^5,...$ and so on can be reduced to smaller powers. For instance, $A^4=A(A^3) = A(2A^2-3A-I)=2A^3-3A^2-A=...$ and I've lowered the power, so now I can reduce $A^3$ again and you see that $A^4\in\mathrm{span}\{I,A,A^2\}$

Comment: This means that in general $E=\mathrm{span}\{A^k:k\in\mathbb N\}$ is equal to $E=\mathrm{span}\{A^k:k=0,\dots,n-1\}$ where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix. Of course, these matrices $I,A,A^2,\dots,A^{n-1}$ need not be linearly independent (think of the case $A=I$) and a smaller generating set (basis) can be found.

Comment: In your example, the characteristic polynomial is $-(x-1)^2(x-2)$; therefore $(A-I)^2(A-2I)=0$, but you can verify that actually also $(A-I)(A-2I)=0$, so already $A^2$ is in the span of $I$ and $A$. Therefore $E=\mathrm{span}\{I,A\}$.

Comment: well I think now Ive just get it
thanks very much ^_^

Comment: An example is better than a thousand theorems, I guess :)